# Invariant rest mass vs Proper velocity

Tags: special-relativity, mass, invariants

For an object (rest mass $m_0$ ) moving with velocity v, we (observers at rest) say that it has energy $E=m(v)$$c^2$.
Where $m(v)$= $m_0$/$\sqrt(1-v^2)$.
Thus, for us, we can say it's mass has increased by $m(v)$ (compared to its rest mass) and it's momentum is $\mathbf P$ = $m(v)$ $v$
.

Suppose now, if we, the observers start moving with velocity $u$ and the velocity of the object relative to us appears as $v'$. Now we know what $v'$ is, using lorrentz transformation, so we can calculate new $E'=m(v')$$c^2$ and  $\mathbf P'$ = $m(v')$ $v'$ and we find they transform exactly like x and t and so they must be the components of the four vector $\mathbf P^\mu$
.

Now, I've also read about proper velocity $\mathbf u^\mu$ = $dx/d\tau$, $\tau$ being the proper time.
And then the four momenta is $\mathbf P^\mu$= $m_0$$\mathbf u^\mu$.

Both explanations of $\mathbf P^\mu$ are correct however one assumes that mass varies as a function of velocity and the other explanation assumes mass is invariant and is $always$ the rest mass $m_0$ and it's the $\mathbf u^\mu$ which brings the transformation. So which is more correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct.

However, the "relativistic mass" concept $m(v)$
is likely to be misused by non-experts,
especially because there are relativistic expressions
that are not the result of
taking ordinary non-relativistic expressions
and replacing mass by  "relativistic mass" (e.g. relativistic kinetic energy).

Thus, pedagogically, it is preferable not to use "relativistic mass".
Instead,
use "[invariant] [rest] mass" $m_0$ and use "relativistic energy" $E=m_0 c^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\right)$, as needed.

Note that in the 4-momentum equation $\mathbf P^\mu = m_0 \mathbf u^\mu$,
the quantity is $\mathbf u^\mu$ is called the 4-velocity. (It is unit-vector tangent to the particle worldline.) ["[Proper velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_velocity)" usually refers to the spatial-component of the 4-velocity, and is usually called the celerity.]

Here are some references:

Einstein Never Approved of Relativistic Mass
The Physics Teacher 47, 336 (2009); https://doi.org/10.1119/1.3204111
Eugene Hecht

The Concept of Mass in the Einstein Year
https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0602037
by L.B. Okun

On the Abuse and Use of Relativistic Mass
https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0504110
by Gary Oas

Comment: Thank you so much for your to-the-point answer!!