# Energy of a $n$-particle system in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity

Consider an inertial frame $S'$. With respect to this frame of reference consider a system of $n$ particles. The $k$-th particle has rest mass $m_{0,k}$ and it moves with speed $u_k$. Can we say that the mass of the system is $$\mathbf{m=\sum_{k=1}^{n}m_{0,k}\gamma_{u_{k}}}$$ with total energy $E=mc^2$ ,where $\gamma_{u_{k}}$ is given by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{{u_k}^2}{c^2}}}$ ? 
And also, how does the relativistic energy expression contain the information about potential energy?

Answer (score 1):

$\sum\gamma_k m_k c^2$ is called the "total relativistic energy" $E_{rel,tot}$.

Although some have called $\frac{1}{c^2}E_{rel,tot}=\sum\gamma_k m_k$ the "relativistic mass",
because of misconceptions by novices, its use is discouraged.
(Further comments at [Invariant rest mass vs Proper velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/606375/invariant-rest-mass-vs-proper-velocity) )

The "invariant mass of the system" (or the "rest mass of the system")
$m_{sys}$ is essentially the magnitude of the total 4-momentum:
\begin{align}m_{sys}c^2
&=\sqrt{\tilde P_{tot}c\cdot \tilde P_{tot}c}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\sum \tilde P_k\right)c\cdot\left(\sum \tilde P_k\right)c}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\sum  E_{rel,k}\right)^2-\left(\sum \vec p_{rel,k}c\right)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\sum  \gamma_k m_k c^2\right)^2-\left(\sum \vec p_{rel,k}c\right)^2}\\
\end{align}

Comment: It should be noted that this discussion is in the context of non-interacting particles. If the particles interact, the potential energy between the particles will affect the mass of the _system_.

Comment: @robphy Then the statement \textit{``as the energy of the system increases its mass also increases''} essentially means that as $E_{rel,tot}$ increases then $\frac{E_{rel,tot}}{c^2} = \sum \gamma_k m_k = m_{rel} $ also increases?

Comment: @Snpr_Physics What is the source of that statement? If someone says "mass" in 2021, it is understood to be the correct mass, i.e., the invariant mass. And it does not necessarily change with an increase in the energy of the system. If you want to refer to the so-called "relativistic mass" then the statement you quote is tautologically correct.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0504110 this article was helpful.